# Topology defined by some convergent sequences

Tags: general-topology

On $\mathbb R^d$ define this notion of convergence
$$x_n\to x\iff \lim_n ||x_n-x||_2 n^{d}=0$$
is there any topology which is endowed with this convergence?

It has the peculiarity that if $x_n$ converges to $x$ in the standard sense you can find a subsequence of $x_n$ such that $x_n\to x$, so balls cannot be open sets

Comment: I see you have accepted my answer. Don't do that, it's not correct!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: As pointed out by @Kavi Rama Murthy, there is a serious flaw in this argument. I'll have to get back to it to see if I'm even right in that it doesn't come from a topology.

There is not.  Take the sequence $n^{-(d+1)}$, which converges to 0 in your definition.

Now look at the sequence $(y_n) = (1,1,2^{-(d+1)}, 2^{-(d+1)}, 3^{-(d+1)}, 3^{-(d+1)},...)$. If your convergence comes from a topology, this sequences would also converge to 0. But

$||y_n - 0||n^d \ge \left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)^{-(d+1)}n^d=2^{d+1}(n-1)^{-(d+1)}n^d=2^{d+1}\frac{1}{n-1}\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)^d$

Comment: The right side converges to $0$, not $\infty$.

Comment: Oh my god, d is constant... Thank you for spotting that silly mistake!

Answer (score 1):

This solution steals the idea from Richard Jensen's answer, but then (hopefully!) correctly proves the conclusion that the convergence notion cannot come from a topology.

Define for $n \ge 1:$ $p_n:=n^{-d-1}$ and $x_n:=(p_n,0,\ldots,0) \in \mathbb R^d$. Then $x_n \rightarrow (0,\ldots,0) \in \mathbb R^d$ in the sense of the problem's definition of convergence.

Now define $y_n:=x_{\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor}$. Since $\lim_{n \to \infty}\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor = \infty$, the sequence $\{y_n\}$ must also converge to $(0,\ldots,0) \in \mathbb R^d$, if this convergence notion is coming from a topology.

But we have for $k\ge 1$

$$\lVert y_{k^2}-(0,\ldots,0)\rVert_2(k^2)^d = \lVert x_k-(0,\ldots,0)\rVert_2(k^2)^d =p_k(k^2)^d =k^{-d-1}k^{2d}=k^{d-1} \ge 1.$$

So the sequence $\{y_n\}$ is clearly not converging to $(0,\ldots,0) \in \mathbb R^d$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry for asking such a silly question but... is the fact that a subsequence of a converging sequence does not converge what proves that this convergence definition does not come from a topology?

Comment: Certainly not a silly question. What you mention is not the reason, because my sequence $\{y_n\}$ is not a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ (it containes most elements of $\{x_n\}$ multiple times). The notion of convergence given in the problem does in fact have the property that a subsequence of a convergent sequence also converges.
My argument (which I only got from Richard Jensen's answer) goes a s follows. Recall the definition of a  convergent sequence in a topological space (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence):

Comment: A point $x$ of the topological space $(X, \tau)$ is a limit of the sequence $\{x_n\}$ if, for every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, there is an $N$ such that, for every $n\ge N$ $x_n \in U$. If the notion of convergence was from a topological space, that would be true for the sequence $\{x_n\}$. That means for each neighbourhood $U$ of $(0,\ldots,0)$ there is an $N(U)$ such that $x_n \in U$ for $n \ge N(U)$. But with the way $\{y_n\}$ was defined, it means that $y_n \in U$ for each $n \ge N(U)^2$. This in turn means that $\{y_n\}$ is convergent in the topological space to $(0,\ldots,0)$.

Comment: @Dog_69 see above

Comment: I see, thanks. I got confused because I thought $\{y_n\}$ was a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ but, as you say, it is not.